# こんな ことしたら心動くんだ. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

Recently I watched a show and the girl did something for the guy and he was moved by the girl's action. I may have heard it wrongly but I
thought I heard the guy said it as:
こんな ことしたら心動くんだ to another friend.
I did a Google translate and it turned out as "I'm moved when ***I*** do this"

Why is it "I" and not "he/she/someone else"?

Then I did a test by changing the the sentence to make it into a probable "when/if", but Google failed to translate the below sentences.
こんな ことされたら心動くんだ. If you do something like this
こんな ことしてくれたら心動くんだ. If you do something like this
こんな ことしてくれば心動くんだ. If you do something like this

I was puzzled as to why the translated answer to all the three above altered sentences was the same, that is "If you do something like this". Are they grammatically missing something?
Kindly advice and correct the sentences if they are wrong. Thank you.

Comment: There is no pronoun in the Japanese sentence so there is no "I" in it, the Google translate is just guessing a pronoun for the English without the context.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks